Word document has links to other docs in onedrive. How to make these documents accessible to others
Ive spent a lot of time on the report and didnt think of this up front. Now I realise that nobody can read my linked documents unless I manually create a shared link for each one and then edit the hyperlink in my document to replace it with the shared link, Thats several days work.
Does anyone have a suggestion to get this done a little quicker and easier.
I'm running out of time.
Any help would be very much appreciated

Best you can do is make the shared links, and save each one to a text file as you make them, keeping them in order.  Then you could possibly use the text to replace the hyperlinks in the document in one fell swoop.  But the link has to exist, so you're going to need valid urls.

I was hoping you you wouldn't say that.
